# Relative clause and its subject

Tags: relative-clauses

I came across this sentence on Cambridge Dictionary

> The central office sets the parameters that guide policy at the local level.

The example comes with a translation in a different language, but I got confused by it.

The translation implies that it is the **central office** that guides policy at the local level instead of the **parameters**.

I thought "that guide policy at the local level" modifies **parameters** instead of **central office**, so it should be the **Parameters** that do the guiding, not **central office** .

So,
Is the translation wrong or my understanding of the sentence is incorrect?

Comment: If you trust *translators,* you are at a great risk! :)

Comment: What do you know about subject - verb agreement?

Comment: Syntactically the relative clause "that guide policy at the local level" modifies "parameters". Semantically, we understand that the central office sets the parameters that provide the guidance, and thus have the ultimate control over policy at local level.

Comment: You really should provide the link.

Answer (score 1):

"**That**" always has a connection to the noun, gerund or clause that stands before it.

Split the sentence:

- The central office sets the parameters.
- The parameters guide policy at the local levels.

Comment: Yes, that connects to its antecedent.